# When did Calvin get Hobbes?

Tags: calvin-and-hobbes

In the very first strip we see:
[image]

Which implies Calvin got Hobbes when he was 6. As this is the first strip, it is quite clear this is intended to be an origin story.

However, in this August 1st, 1989, strip, we see:
[image]

Which implies Calvin has had him since he was a little kid. When exactly did Calvin get Hobbes? Is there another strip or interview with Bill Watterson that clears things up?

Comment: Remember Dr. House's first rule. Everybody (and every tiger) lies.

Comment: There is another comic that implies Hobbes is a family heirloom.

Comment: what Buzz said. Hobbes belonged to one of the parents (I can't recall which at the moment)

Comment: Downvoted. The first strip only implies that Calvin has set up a trap to catch a tiger.

Comment: @Buzz Care to share it?

Comment: @motoDrizzt Since it's the very first strip, I think it's clear to imply that's how he got it.

Comment: @motoDrizzt Watterson clearly intended it to be an origin story, as implied in the answer.

Comment: If I knew when that comic was, I would have shared it.  I have read all of *Calvin & Hobbes*, but it's been a while.

Comment: @Buzz So have I, and while I recall that the comic said Calvin's dad also dragged around a tiger, I don't remember it saying it was the same tiger. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Maybe the family had Hobbes for generations, and he was around when Calvin was small (a time Calvin admits not remembering), and the he was stoved away on a lof or something. Then, one day, Calvin's dad finds it, and being the practical joker we know he is, hangs it in the tree as a surprise for Calvin.

Answer (score 20):

According to the [Calvin and Hobbes wiki](https://calvinandhobbes.fandom.com/wiki/Hobbes), when Watterson made the first strip, he had intended it as an explanation for where Hobbes came from, but in the *Tenth Anniversary Book*, he wrote that he had changed his mind at some point on Hobbes' origin, instead preferring it to be unexplained as he felt any explanation was "unnecessary and detrimental to the feel of the strip." Therefore later strips implied that Hobbes had always been around.

Comment: Can you provide a direct quote?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't have that book, so I'm relying on the information on the wiki.

Comment: A quick glance at the page they seem to be referring to would suggest that this quote isn't entirely accurate

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answer above, in the *Tenth Anniversary Book*, page 29, which shows the very first strip, the comment by Bill Watterson says

> This was the first Calvin and Hobbes strip, published November 18, 1985. At the time, I thought it was important to establish how Calvin and Hobbes got together, but now I think was unnecessary.